# Maven alternate "stable-test" phase which skips failing tests

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working on a open source repository which has hundreds of tests, some of which are failing. The number of tests are quite a few, which will take time to fix. I also want to have a nightly run of tests so I know I don't introduce new regressions. To achieve this, I wanted to have an alternate "mvn stable-tests" target which is essentially the same as "mvn test" but which excludes a list of tests which I specify in the pom.xml file. How can I do this? I currently use maven-surefire-plugin for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a profile with pluginManagement for the maven-surefire-plugin that uses the include/exclude controls for tests to exclude what isn't working yet.